# Edrawing API - Content of the "ContentControl" must be a single element

Tags: c#, wpf, api

Im new in WPF. I want to connect to Edrawings. I used the following instruction:

https://www.codestack.net/edrawings-api/gettings-started/wpf/

I did the implementation already in windowsforms which works perfectly. In Wpf i get the following error:

"The content of the "ContentControl" must be a single item"

I found some solution stuff here. But unfortunately nothing is working for my problem.

In addition, here is the Code (same as in the like):

```
namespace PDM
{

public partial class eDrawingsHostControl : UserControl
{

    private EModelViewControl m_Ctrl;
    public eDrawingsHostControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        var ctrl = new eDrawingHost();
        ctrl.ControlLoaded += OnControlLoaded;
        host.Child = ctrl;
        this.AddChild(host); // --- Here I got the error ---

    }   

    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FilePathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilePathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FilePath), typeof(string),
            typeof(eDrawingsHostControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFilePathPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnFilePathPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as eDrawingsHostControl).OpenFile(e.NewValue as string);
    }

    private void OpenFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (m_Ctrl == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("eDrawings control is not loaded");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) || !File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            m_Ctrl.CloseActiveDoc("");
        }
        else
        {
            m_Ctrl.OpenDoc(filePath, false, false, false, "");
        }
    }

    private void OnControlLoaded(EModelViewControl ctrl)
    {
        m_Ctrl = ctrl;
        m_Ctrl.OnFinishedLoadingDocument += OnFinishedLoadingDocument;
        m_Ctrl.OnFailedLoadingDocument += OnFailedLoadingDocument;
    }

    private void OnFailedLoadingDocument(string fileName, int errorCode, string errorString)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"{fileName} failed to loaded: {errorString}");
    }

    private void OnFinishedLoadingDocument(string fileName)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"{fileName} loaded");
    }
}
```

And here is the xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="PDM.Edrawing"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:PDM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Edrawing" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <myControls:eDrawingsHostControl Grid.Row="0" FilePath="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txtFilePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtFilePath"/>
</Grid>
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Can you give more details about the error? Is it a runtime error or is it a compilation error?
If it's a compilation error, can you point us to the exact line of code it's throwing the error?
If it's a runtime error, I would consider including a stacktrace as well so we can get more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `this.AddChild(host);` with `this.Content=host;`. Be aware, that such a way host will be the only content.
If you want to have some additional controls in the `UserControl` you will have to define the `ControlTemplate` with these controls and e.g. `ContentPresenter` in it.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much 